# color points on plot depending of a value of a column

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset with 2 columns. With `plot(ds$values)` I get all the points in black.

Now consider that I have one second column that gives me categories as strings. Notice that I don't know the categories names. How do I plot each category with a different colour.

A simple: `plot(ds$values, col=someFn(ds$categories))`?

Adding an index would be good but not required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key here is to transform your categorical variable from character to factor. You can simply wrap it in `factor` as you pass it to the `col` argument in `plot`. Here's a simple example:

```
set.seed(1)
plot(sample(1:10,20,TRUE), col=factor(sample(letters[1:3],20,TRUE)))
```

Of course, you may want to pick a different color palette than the default.

[image]

Comment: I have two columns of boolean, how to use these two columns to mark different colors, I have total of 4 combination of the columns.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Thomas' description above:

```
plot(ds$values, col=factor(ds$categories))
```